# Load image from respective res/drawable folder Android

Tags: android, image, load, drawable

I have a custom class `ButtonImage`.

```
public ButtonImage(Activity activity) {

        face1 = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("face1", "drawable" , activity.getPackageName());
        face1i.setImageResource(face1);
...
```

I have `res/drawable`, and others (`drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`), then I wanna load the faces (I have 4), then when I create the `ButtonImage` I have `NullPointerException` on these line (`face1 = activity...`)

How I can load the images from drawable folder depending of the (ldpi,hdpi, mdpi) folder, I have the 4 images on each folder.

Sorry my english, I hope that you can understand me

Comment: Can you show how this `ButtonImage` is constructed? I feel that `activity` is probably null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow Sorry.

I forgot create the Imageviews objetcs;

```
face1 = new ImageView(activity);
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer to mark this question as answered. It's *very* important for this site to mark questions as answered. Think of it as an "archiving". It helps a lot! Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I have to wait any time yet

Comment: OK, just remembering since you're new here. :)